AWS S3 : Method not found: 'Boolean Amazon.AWSConfigs.get_InitializeCollections()'
I'm a newbie to AWS S3 and on my first attempt to upload a file to S3 I get:
"{"Method not found: 'Boolean Amazon.AWSConfigs.get_InitializeCollections()'."}" on calling :                       PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest
AWSSDK.S3 3.7.308.4 installed.
Language is c#
                    // Create a client
                    AmazonS3Client client = new AmazonS3Client();

                    // Create a PutObject request
                    PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest
                    {
                        BucketName = "xxx",
                        Key = "yyy",
                    };
                   


Hi and welcome to Stack overflow. How are uploading the file? what are the settings for S3? If you are uploading through your browser or CLI, then stack overflow may not be the right forum for this question - try re:Post. Also, being a newbie is not an excuse to ask the question poorly. You might find reading the site [help] useful when it comes to [ask], and this question checklist.

Thanks for the suggestions. Here is the code in full :
// Create a client
AmazonS3Client client = new AmazonS3Client();
// Create a PutObject request
PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest
{
BucketName = "yyyy",
Key =xxxx,
};
I will be uploading the file via a browser, but have not got to that part of the code yet.
the setting are the same as I use for DynamoDB (in web.config)- in the same application.

Please update the question with this code and where are you getting the erro. Also put a tag indicating what language it is. Finally, please explain how is DynamoDB relevant to your question (if it is). And you probably want to remove references to being a newbie (leave one - if you feel strongly about the need to say it)

OK. it's a good (although very small) first step. Now, tell us about the error. I assume you get it during runtime. Be more specific how you get it. Also, the error refers to AWSConfigs. Your code must be getting some authentication information. Put that part in the question as well. You probably want to review the question (or delete this one and start from the beginning. Your error has nothing to do with uploading the file, does it? Asking the question correctly (and reading the error message) is 80% of the solution. Good luck

Found a solution :) , but not the cause. :(
Emptied the bin folder and it came to life.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

I had some similar error message for my case I was used nlog to push the loggs to AWSCloudwatch.
seems it's expecting any one of the way to get the credentials details for initlize.

Either environment values
Profile
accessKey & secretKey to be passed

Any of this missing in your application then this error message shows.
